# os.listdir() won't go after nine files

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Hello i am trying to make a program that would automaticly go to imgur, enter the name that you typed and download top 10 images.Everything is working except the os library.When i try to do os.listdir() after nine files it wont show anymore files.I tried googling and found nothing if you see something that i messed up please tell me.Thanks in advance.Sorry for bad grammar.
Here is the code sample:

```
#! python3
import requests, os, sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

os.chdir('imgur/')
broswer =  webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\{YOUR USERNAME}\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')
broswer.get('https://imgur.com/')
broswer.maximize_window()

search_bar = broswer.find_element_by_tag_name('input')
search_bar.send_keys('happy')
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

pictures = broswer.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')
for i in range(1, 11):
    res = requests.get(pictures[i].get_attribute('src'))
    try:
        res.raise_for_status()
    except:
        print('Link doesnt exist')
    
    if os.listdir() == []:
        picture = open('picture1.png', 'wb')
    else:
        picture = open('picture' + str(int(os.listdir()[-1][7:-4]) + 1) + '.png', 'wb')
        print(os.listdir())

    for chunk in res.iter_content(100000):
        picture.write(chunk)

    picture.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
os.listdir(".") #u missed adding address
```